# how to create regex to fetch the particular(bug.updateBug) string from the log file

Tags: c#, .net, regex

how to create regex to fetch the particular(bug.updateBug) string from the following line available in the log file as follows:
WX Edit Bug: 3550704 Server: servername User:testuser appGUID: appguidvalue Elapsed Time: 624ms method:bug.updateBug  Date: Wed May 01 09:38:01 PDT 2013

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication59
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> textLines
                           = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\testlocation\", "*.*")
                             .Select(filePath => File.ReadLines(filePath))
                             .SelectMany(line => line);

            List<string> users = new List<string>();
            Regex r = new Regex("^.*WX\\sADVSearch(.*)50\\]$");
            foreach (string Line in textLines)
            {
                if (r.IsMatch(Line))
                {
                    users.Add(Line);
                }
            }
            string[] textLines1 = new List<string>(users).ToArray();
            int countlines = textLines1.Count();
            Console.WriteLine("WX_ADVSearch=" + countlines);
            // keep screen from going away
            // when run from VS.NET
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have data in the form of something like key/value pair. Try using this regex:

```
(?<=method\:)([^ ]+)
```

Here:

**method** is the key whose value is to be find.
and any thing except the next key is supposed to be its value.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> textLines = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\testlocation\", "*.*")
                             .Select(filePath => File.ReadLines(filePath))
                             .SelectMany(line => line);

            //List<string> users = new List<string>();
            //Regex r = new Regex("^.*WX\\sADVSearch(.*)50\\]$");
            string text = String.Join("",textLines.ToArray());

            MatchCollection mcol = Regex.Matches(text,"(?<=method\:)([^ ]+)");
            //foreach (string Line in textLines)
            //{
            //    if (r.IsMatch(Line))
            //    {
            //        users.Add(Line);
            //    }
            //}
            //string[] textLines1 = new List<string>(users).ToArray();
            int countlines = mcol.Count; //textLines1.Count();
            Console.WriteLine("WX_ADVSearch=" + countlines);
            // keep screen from going away
            // when run from VS.NET
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Well actually i would like to extract the number of occurances in all the lines present in log file which has User:github and method:bug.updatebug.The example of one such line is as follows:WX Edit Bug: 3550704 Server: servername User:github appGUID: appguidvalue Elapsed Time: 624ms method:bug.updateBug  Date: Wed May 01 09:38:01 PDT 2013

Comment: You can use `MatchCollection` class with `Regex.Matches()` it help you to find the number of matches found by the Regex engine.

Comment: hmm. actually i am new to regex. can you please share the exact regex to be used as i specified in my earlier comment. Thanks

Comment: Actually i want to specifically get the count for the entries in my log where the value after method:bug.updateBug.Refer the log files where there are 2 different values present after method:    as follows:WX Edit Bug: 3550704 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:github appGUID: 601642e8-805b-486b-92a4-166270ce3688 Elapsed Time: 624ms method:bug.updateBug  Date: Wed May 01 09:38:01 PDT 2013
WX Edit Bug: 3550709 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:github appGUID: 601642e8-805b-486b-92a4-166270ce3688 Elapsed Time: 379ms method:bug.addNote  Date: Wed May 01 14:18:24 PDT 2013

Comment: Actually i want to specifically get the count for the entries in my log where the value after method:bug.updateBug.Refer the log files where there are 2 different values present after method: as follows:WX Edit Bug: 3550704 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:github appGUID: 601642e8-805b-486b-92a4-166270ce3688 Elapsed Time: 624ms method:bug.updateBug Date: Wed May 01 09:38:01 PDT 2013 WX Edit Bug: 3550709 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:github appGUID: 601642e8-805b-486b-92a4-166270ce3688 Elapsed Time: 379ms method:bug.addNote Date: Wed May 01 14:18:24 PDT 2013